# what is wrong with my nginx.conf

Tags: nginx

I am trying to have a subdirectory for a virtual host.. so say xxx.xxx.xxx/vhost1 and xxx.xxx.xxx/vhost2. I have the following config file:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes  4;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    tcp_nodelay        on;

    gzip  on;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

    server {
        listen   80 default;

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/localhost.access.log;

        location / {
                root   /var/www/nginx-default;
                index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        location /adminapi {
                if (-f $request_filename) {
                        break;
                }

                rewrite  ^/(.*)$  /index.php?$1  last;
                root   /var/www/api/src/frapi/admin/public;
                index  index.php;
        }

        location /api {
                 if (-f $request_filename) {
                        break;
                 }

                rewrite  ^/(.*)$  /index.php?$1  last;
                root   /var/www/api/src/frapi/admin/public;
                index  index.php;
        }

        location /phpmyadmin {
                 root   /usr/share/phpmyadmin;
                 index  index.php;

                 fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                 fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/phpmyadmin/index.php;
                 include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                 fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /index.php;
        }

        location /doc {
                root   /usr/share;
                autoindex on;
                allow 127.0.0.1;
                deny all;
        }

        location /images {
                root   /usr/share;
                autoindex on;
        }

        #error_page  404  /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        #error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        #location = /50x.html {
        #       root   /var/www/nginx-default;
        #}

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
                #proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index  index.php;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/www/nginx-default$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny  all;
        }
}


}
```

the xxx.xxx.xxx/phpmyadmin works, but the layout is wrong.. I am guessing that it can't find the css and images... what do I need to change?

the other xxx.xxx.xxx/vhost does not work at all

Answer (score 0):

For your phpmyadmin not finding its CSS, you should be able to diagnose that either by using a client-side tool like Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools to see what requests are failing and what URIs they are requesting, or by tailing `/var/log/nginx/access.log` and `/var/log/nginx/error.log` to see the same information from the server side.

For your other question about nginx not displaying `http://sample.com/vhost1` etc, your root directory is configured to read from `/var/www/nginx-default`. So you should have a directory at `/var/www/nginx-default/vhost1` with a file named `index.html` or `index.htm`. Or if you'd like the URI `/vhost1` to point to a different filesystem location, simply add another block to your configuration file, eg:

```
location /vhost1 {
    root   /home/sample/www/vhost1;
    index  index.html;
}

location /vhost2 {
    root   /var/www/vhost2;
    index  index.html;
}
```

Comment: if you see in my code above vhost1 = admin api and I did have a location /adminapi there.. but still I cant navigate there

Comment: the url to the css and image are at xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/./themes/original/img, where as this is not true.. I am not sure what . is here...